# Symfony - Compare Word with caracters / 3.4

Tags: php

Hey guys my question is simple how can i check if a word contains a series of characters.

Exemple : Check if `IAmATest` as `Test` in it ... ?

`Test@gmail.com` --> `gmail.com` = true

`Test@Yahoo.eu` --> `gmail.com` = false

Comment: Have a look at this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: If you want to do more complex stuff take a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php instead of many if/elseif conditions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strpos('Test@gmail.com', 'gmail.com') !== false) {
    // word contains characters
} else {
    // word doesn't contains characters
}
```